# How can I convert collection laravel to array?

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections, laravel-5.6

My code like this :

```
$test = $this->vendorRepository->getVendor($request->get('q'));
```

If I `dd($test)`, the result is collection like this :

[image]

I want to convert it to array

I try like this :

```
dd($test->toArray());
```

The result like this :

[image]

value of id changed to 0

Why did it happen? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: i think your first image is not a collection. Can you add the output from starting ? you can access your data like this ‘$test->name’

Comment: @rkj I had update it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be because your ID field is a string but laravel is expecting it to be an auto-incrementing integer.

Try adding this to the top of your model:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```